# Split Terminator with external command?

Tags: gnome-terminator

I'd like to be able to add frames (not tabs) to terminator from gnome-pie or something similar. "--help" didn't seem to have anything, but do you guys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To simulate any key combination, what comes to my head is to use `xdotool` tool.

Install `$ sudo apt-get install xdotool`

Usage:

```
$ xdotool key [key]+[key]
```

e.g.

```
$ xdotool key ctrl+shift+o # To split horizontal
$ xdotool key ctrl+shift+e # To split vertical
```

Having this you can make it easier creating some aliases.

```
$ alias splith='xdotool key ctrl+shift+o'
$ alias splitv='xdotool key ctrl+shift+e'
```

[image]

Give a try.

**UPDATE**

Ok lets found a solution.

I found a utility to execute commands from other terminals in [here.](http://www.humbug.in/2010/utility-to-send-commands-or-data-to-other-terminals-ttypts/)

Create a file `$ vim ttyecho.c`, copy this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void print_help(char *prog_name) {
        printf("Usage: %s [-n] DEVNAME COMMAND\n", prog_name);
        printf("Usage: '-n' is an optional argument if you want to push a new line at the end of the text\n");
        printf("Usage: Will require 'sudo' to run if the executable is not setuid root\n");
        exit(1);
    }

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *cmd, *nl = "\n";
    int i, fd;
    int devno, commandno, newline;
    int mem_len;
    devno = 1; commandno = 2; newline = 0;
    if (argc < 3) {
        print_help(argv[0]);
    }
    if (argc > 3 && argv[1][0] == '-' && argv[1][1] == 'n') {
        devno = 2; commandno = 3; newline=1;
    } else if (argc > 3 && argv[1][0] == '-' && argv[1][1] != 'n') {
        printf("Invalid Option\n");
        print_help(argv[0]);
    }
    fd = open(argv[devno],O_RDWR);
    if(fd == -1) {
        perror("open DEVICE");
        exit(1);
    }
    mem_len = 0;
    for ( i = commandno; i < argc; i++ ) {
        mem_len += strlen(argv[i]) + 2;
        if ( i > commandno ) {
            cmd = (char *)realloc((void *)cmd, mem_len);
        } else { //i == commandno
            cmd = (char *)malloc(mem_len);
        }

        strcat(cmd, argv[i]);
        strcat(cmd, " ");
    }
    if (newline == 0)
        usleep(225000);
      for (i = 0; cmd[i]; i++)
        ioctl (fd, TIOCSTI, cmd+i);
      if (newline == 1)
        ioctl (fd, TIOCSTI, nl);
    close(fd);
    free((void *)cmd);
    exit (0);
}
```

Then execute `make` + file

```
$ make ttyecho
$ sudo chown root:root ttyecho
$ sudo cp ttyecho /usr/bin
```

Now try it, check in the terminator terminal `tty`

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/0
```

In other terminal execute the following

```
$ ttyecho -n /dev/pts/0 splith
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know about that. I want the same effect but with a command, something like `terminator --new-tab` but with frames.

Comment: @AidanEdwards I edited.

Comment: But wouldn't that only allow me to do it in that terminal?

Comment: @AidanEdwards In the terminal space you're placed in

Comment: I stated it my question, I want to be able to run it from outside of Terminator.

Comment: Cool tool, though.

Comment: @AidanEdwards I found a solution. Give a try.

Comment: Is there a way to change the thing that tty references so it's the same every time, or even the same everyt time in tht last active terminal?

Comment: Evry terminal you open will get a different `tty`, those are uniq until the terminal space is closed

Comment: Dang, So I can't have a static shortcut or something that just points to the last active terminator terminal.

Comment: I might be able to do something with `ls -lu /dev/pts/ | grep aidan`

Comment: @AidanEdwards How were you thinking to execute a command in `gnome-terminal` in example, and split a terminator workspace? Possibly I didn't finish to understand the real thing

Comment: Do you know of a way to run a script when a terminal gains focus?

Comment: I want to execute the command from a `.deskop` file, `gnome-pie`, or something similar.

Comment: [Here's a gist for posterity](https://gist.github.com/Aidoboy/481839e177d0ad04fba6) of my progress if anyone ever wants it, but I realized that it would be easier to just drag the frame out of the new window to an old one, the effort just isn't worth it. Would need to be tracking processes, cleaning up odd ends, managing profiles, it would just be nuts.

Answer (score 1):

This is an addendum to tachomi's excellent [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261635/18887); please upvote it.

AFAIK there is no way to split terminator with (e.g.) an external DBUS command, so you need to use a keystroke hack as proposed in the other answer. To send terminator the keystrokes, you need to make sure it's active first. One way to do this is as follows. In my case, I use terminator as an always-on "pop-up" terminal, activated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. My script checks to see if it's hidden, then makes it appear by emulating <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, otherwise if it's visible, but not in the front, it activates the window.

If you don't use it as a pop-up terminal, then this should probably work anyway, and just never go through that conditional.

```
windowlist=$(xprop -root | sed -rn 's/_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING\(WINDOW\): window id # (.*)/\1/p' | tr -d ',')
terminator_visible=false
for i in $windowlist; do
  [[ $(xprop -id $i | grep WM_CLASS\(STRING\)) == 'WM_CLASS(STRING) = "terminator", "Terminator"' ]] && terminator_visible=true && term_id=$i
done

if [[ $terminator_visible == false ]]; then # it's hidden
  xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+space
elif [[ $(xprop -id $(xdotool getactivewindow) | grep WM_CLASS\(STRING\)) != 'WM_CLASS(STRING) = "terminator", "Terminator"' ]]; then # it's visible, but not active
  xdotool windowactivate $term_id 2> /dev/null
fi
```

After running this script to activate the window, then just run the `xdotool` commands as per the other answer, i.e. one of the following. I'd also suggest using `--clearmodifiers` (see `man xdotool` for more information).

```
xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+shift+o
xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+shift+e
```

Answer (score 1):

These days you can use `remotinator hsplit`: https://terminator-gtk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advancedusage.html#remotinator

I was looking for this today, and just posting this here in case someone else (or future me) finds this post too.